# Why is this 8-puzzle solvable?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle, inversion

So i am writing a program to solve 8 puzzle using BFS,A*, and UCS. The goal state is **fixed** according to the assignment which is given as:

```
Goal State:
|1 2 3|
|8   4|
|7 6 5|
```

```
My Initial State:
|  1 2| 
|8 4 3| 
|7 6 5|
```

However, upon writing a `getInvCount(int [] a)` method:

```
public static boolean getInvCount(int [] a)
{
    int [] arr = a;
    int inv_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[j]){
                inv_count++;
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(inv_count);
```

I realize that the **initial puzzle has 9 inversions** which is an odd number. Yet the **program successfully finds the solution.**
Is there something I am missing in the requirements for a puzzle to be deemed solvable?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getInvCount` function is only valid for the "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" goal state. An "inversion" is when two tiles are *in a different order than they are in the goal state*. The comparison `arr[i] > arr[j]` is only a correct check for an inversion if the goal state is strictly increasing.

Comment: Okay so in this case what would be the best way to check the number of inversions since arr[i] > arr[j]  wont work?